# Running Forward vs. Backwards and Escaping Attack

Tags: overwatch

How much of a speed difference is there between running forwards and backwards when someone is attacking you.  I know there are speed differences between the characters themselves, of course.  However, I'm trying to figure out the best way to avoid attacks such as Winston's Ultimate when he's attacking you specifically, and this is also assuming either no escape abilities or they're all on cooldown.  Is it better to turn around and run, hoping for the best, or backpedal and strafe and try to move out of range?

Answer (score 4):

According to Redditer SpriteGuy_000, who does extensive testing on in-game mechanics,

> running backwards has no effect on movement speed.

[source](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tb7xg_EmtkqgR7da6IDMcFjdEsFkefcW_78mAIRKp0w/edit#gid=1521377263)

Comment: +1, Even without detailed notes on the tests done, the level of effort clearly expended makes that pretty convincing.

Answer (score 0):

It's situational. You move *fastest* if you run forward and change directions with your mouse. This might get you behind cover before you die, for instance. However, you won't know what your opponent is doing, and you won't be able to return fire, neither of which are ideal. On the other hand, trying to backpedal into cover might mean you misjudge a doorway or get stuck on something. Just don't do what I do and constantly strafe left and right, which makes your hero uselessly wiggle in place. So many embarrassing killcams.

Comment: Sounds like your explicit answer is that "yes, you move faster going forward". Does "and change directions with your mouse" imply you somehow move faster while turning?

Comment: My evidence is [admittedly anecdotal](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/3vfbj1/how_important_is_backpedal_in_fps_games/), and I forgot to test this over the weekend, but consensus does seem to be that you move faster forward than backward. The reason you would want to change direction with your mouse is that you keep moving at top speed, since you're still moving "forward" (holding the W key).

Comment: So when you reference changing directions with the mouse, you're saying that as opposed to changing directions via strafing, not as opposed to just moving in a straight line.

Comment: Any time you change directions by pressing a WASD key (switching from W to S or A to D), you suffer a small momentum penalty as your character slows down and then moves the other way. Turning with the mouse avoids this issue and basically allows you to change directions for free. On top of that, running forward with W is a bit faster than backpedaling with S, so if you turn with the mouse while holding W you maintain top speed.

Comment: Alright, I got ya. For what it's worth, that last comment is clearer and more informative than your actual answer. Might consider editing. I'd upvote at that point. Others probably would as well.

Answer (score -1):

I can't surely answer about the speed differences, but strategically saying, the main advantage of facing an attacker that will surely deal damage/outright kill you, is **to damage him back**. Even if you don't manage to kill him before you die, or even get a double-KO (in case of projectile weapons like Hanzo and Lúcio), you can damage him enough to put him out of the picture for a while - Looking for a healer or a healthpack, taking him out of the question for a few seconds, or even having a teammate finish him off.

Even in a dire situation like Winston's ult, he's not invincible, he only has more health. I've managed to kill him multiple times during his ult, because his damage is actually pretty low, the worse part is the knockback, which is mostly harmless depending on the map.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question though; whether or not moving backwards is slower than moving forwards.

Comment: A lot of the movement skilled characters might be strategically better off turning around rather than facing an attacker to **damage him back**. For example D.Va's jump jet and the fact her headshot zone is in the front of her Mekka makes turning around showing her back a big advantage.